# Getting "Listener not registered" with status code 13 with SensorsApi

Tags: android, listener, google-fit

I implemented a custom DataSource for step counter and when I want to register a listener, it fails with Listener not registered and status code=13. If I use the function findDataSources() it works well, but I wanted to add a listener on my datasource. Do you know what the problem is? Thank you!

Here is the code:

```
    public GoogleApiClient buildFitnessClient() {
     mFitnessClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.SESSIONS_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .useDefaultAccount()
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connected to fitness API");
                    registerFitnessDataListener();
                }
                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

                }
            })
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Fitness Connection failed");
                    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
                        retryFitnessConnect();
                     return;
                    }
                }
            })
            .build();
    mFitnessClient.connect();
    return mFitnessClient;
}

   private void registerFitnessDataListener() {
    mListener = new OnDataPointListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
            for (Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                Value val = dataPoint.getValue(field);
                Log.i(TAG, "Detected DataPoint field: " + field.getName());
                Log.i(TAG, "Detected DataPoint value: " + val);
                Log.i(TAG, "Detected DataPoint startTime: " + dataPoint.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));                
            }
        }
    };

    DataSource dataSourceSteps=new DataSource.Builder()
            .setAppPackageName("myPackageName")
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setName("steps")
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
            .build();

    Fitness.SensorsApi.add(
            mFitnessClient,
            new SensorRequest.Builder()
                    .setDataSource(dataSourceSteps)
                    .setSamplingRate(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build(),
            mListener)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Listener registered!");
                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Listener not registered "+status.getStatusCode());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The  ['Sensors API'](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/sensors) provides access to raw sensor data streams from sensors available on the Android device. To add a listener to receive data of a particular fitness data or from a specific data source, use the  ['Sensorspi.add'](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/SensorsApi) method.

Below is a sample code snippet how to construct listener:

```
mListener = new OnDataPointListener() {
@Override
public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
for (Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
Value val = dataPoint.getValue(field);
Log.i(TAG, "Detected DataPoint field: " + field.getName());
Log.i(TAG, "Detected DataPoint value: " + val);
}
}
};

Fitness.SensorsApi.add(
mClient,
new SensorRequest.Builder()
.setDataSource(dataSource) // Optional but recommended for custom data sets.
.setDataType(dataType) // Can't be omitted.
.setSamplingRate(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.build(),
mListener)
.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
@Override
public void onResult(Status status) {
if (status.isSuccess()) {
Log.i(TAG, "Listener registered!");
} else {
Log.i(TAG, "Listener not registered.");
}
}
});
```

Comment: This is the same as I have, the only difference is that I create a dataSource and add it in SensorRequest, and then I get this error.